# How to use style insides a txt variable in php?

Tags: php, html, css

I send an email foe my users after they register in my website like the following:

```
        --------------------------------
        Hello world 
        --------------------------------
        gogogo
        http://example.com/ ailesine katıldığınız için teşekkürler.

        Giriş Bilgileriniz:

        Kullanıcı Adı:  xxxxxx
        Şifre:          xxxxxx

        Buradan giriş yapın: http://example.com/?page=login.php

        Saygılar
        example.com Yönetimi.

        --------------------------------
        Sosyal ağlarda takipte kalın:
        Google : https://plus.google.com/+example
        Twitter: https://twitter.com/example
        Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/example
        Youtube: http://www.youtube.com/user/example
        --------------------------------
```

I want to add colors to this email I want to make the first part as red color and i want to make links at the bottom not clickable .

I tried to color the txt using some html tags and style attributes but it send it just as following:

```
        <span style="color:red;">--------------------------------
        Hello world
        --------------------------------</span>
        gogogo
        http://example.com/ ailesine katıldığınız için teşekkürler.

        Giriş Bilgileriniz:

        Kullanıcı Adı:  xxxxxx
        Şifre:          xxxxxx

        Buradan giriş yapın: http://example.com/?page=login.php

        Saygılar
        example.com Yönetimi.

        --------------------------------
        Sosyal ağlarda takipte kalın:
        Google : https://plus.google.com/+example
        Twitter: https://twitter.com/example
        Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/example
        Youtube: http://www.youtube.com/user/example
        --------------------------------
```

Note I user php function to send the email and the eamil information is saved in a php variable call `$messege`

How can color the text and make links not clickable ?

Comment: Set headers, that it's not plain text, but HTML content. If using some library for sending email, they have separate methods for plain email and HTML email content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my suggestion would be to use `$message` completely in `HTML` format

```
$message = "<html>
  <body style='background-color:grey>
    <center>
        <b> HTML email</b> <br>
         your text and adesign  
    </center>

  </body>
</html>";
```

then

```
   $headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";  /*<= this is very important */

   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Here is a good read about it :  [**css tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)

Comment: I'd prefer to use **[heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)**

Comment: @HashemQolami : hmmm....never worked on it, so can't suggest...i find `html` way for easy for myself :)